# Five riddles with the same answer

Tags: riddle

**The answer has to be able to answer all of the riddles below.**

1. Wears a suit.. but is not a businessman?
2. Likes candy.. but is not a child?
3. Owns animals.. but is not a zoologist?
4. Has workers.. but is not a manager?
5. Has super powers.. but is not a superhero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it:

> Santa Claus?

1. Wears a suit.. but is not a businessman?

> He wears a red and white Santa suit.

2. Likes candy.. but is not a child?

> He likes candy canes and Christmas candy.

3. Owns animals.. but is not a zoologist?

> He owns reindeer that pull his sled.

4. Has workers.. but is not a manager?

> He has elves that make gifts.

5. Has super powers.. but is not a superhero?

> He can deliver gifts really quickly, and fly a sleigh.